# HTML Link is just showing as plain text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a very weird problem that never experienced in past!! I have a html link in my website as follows:

```
<div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it is showing as plain text "Facebook", not as clickable link text!

What can be the possible reasons behind this kind of weird behavior?? Expecting help from the expert guys!!

Here is the Complete Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "News";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/pixeden-icons.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/main.css">

<div id="banner-area">
    <img src="~/Content/images/banner/banner2.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" />
    <div class="parallax-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Subpage title start -->
    <div class="banner-title-content">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>News and Events</h2>
            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("News and Events", "News", "NewsAndEvents")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Subpage title end -->
</div><!-- Banner area end -->


<div>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">FaceBook</a>
</div>


<div class="container archive">
    <div class="pageContentArea archive-content">


        <div class="timeline-wrap">
            <article>
                <time datetime="2015-01-31 08:30:45.687">26 jan,2015</time>

                <div class="article_inner">
                    <h1>The Lego Movie” snubbed at the Oscars</h1>
                    <img src="~/Content/images/News/img1.jpg" alt="" />


                    <p>
                        Pellentesque quis sapien eleifend aliquet, morbi ideru dictum finibus blandit. Phasellus a iaculis hiri habitase platea dictumst neque, tincinq mangas.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                    <!-- <a class="readMore" href="#">Read More..</a> -->
                </div>
            </article>


        </div><!--timeline-wrap-->

    </div><!--pageContentArea-->

</div><!--container-->




@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/main.js"></script>
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Could be that you have something like `a { text-decoration: none; color: #000000 }` in your stylesheet

Comment: is the link is still clickable. Even though it's doesn't appear as link

Comment: Examine the link element in the developer console (right click on the element -> inspect)

Comment: I pretty sure that there's an element overlapping the div. :)

Comment: Most probably you have some stylesheets in your document which set styles to your `a` elements. You can find it out with your Chrome dev tools.

Comment: please post more code since this is working fine.

Comment: Could you please post your code

Comment: I bet @elementzero23 has put his finger on the problem.

Comment: @elementzero23 No Luck yet!!

Comment: @TanvirArjel what happens if you (left) click on the link? Does it work?

Comment: Can you please post more code then? Because the small piece you have got in your question **does** work

Comment: Could you try giving it or raising it's z-axis for a while?

Comment: @elementzero23 complete code has been added!!

Comment: I copied your code into an empty razor page in my project and if I remove your action links in your `.breadcrumb` it works fine. Can you post your css and javascript as well? (main.js and main.css)

Comment: Are you running this on an online code editor or have you tried deploying it into an HTML file?

Comment: try to add z-index for the <a>, maybe some div hiding the content

Comment: You really should build a working sample. Your 'Complete Code' works fine. I can't see the problem.

Comment: Minimal working example should be provided, displaying the problem.

Comment: When you hover over the text there should be a link that appears bottom left of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in your html syntax. Everything is okay with `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/">FaceBook</a>`. Maybe it's overridden by some styles `(text-decoration: none)` in your css file, which is included in `<head>` section. To debug the problem, try to set `text-decoration:underline`(default value) to your anchor tag, make it from browser inspect to be sure, that it won't be overridden by the other styles or script.